# Using a constructor in Java

Tags: java

Question #3 for the day. I've got to design a program that can read in a specific Radius from a user, then display A/D/C of the relevant circle. I've written up the constructor I need to do this, but I seem to have gotten confused on what I'm supposed to do with it.

How do I take what I've got in the constructor and use it in main?

Relevant constructor code:

```
public class GetCircle {
private float radius;
private double diameter,circumference,area;

public GetCircle(float getRadius, double setDiameter, double setCircumference, double setArea){
    radius=getRadius;
    diameter=setDiameter;
    circumference=setCircumference;     
    area=setArea;
}
public void setRadius(float getRadius){
    radius=getRadius;
}
public float getRadius(){
    return radius;
}   
public void setDiameter(double setDiameter){
    diameter=setDiameter;
}
public double setDiameter(){
    return diameter;
}
public void setCircumference(double setCircumference){
    circumference=setCircumference;
}       
public double setCircumference(){
    return circumference;
}
public void setArea(double setArea){
    area=setArea;
}
public double setArea(){
    return area;
}
public void answer(){
    System.out.println("The Radius that you specified was: " + getRadius());
    System.out.println("The Diameter of your circle is: " + setDiameter());
    System.out.println("The Circumference of your circle is: " + setCircumference());
    System.out.println("The Area of your circle is: " + setArea());
    }
```

}

Relevant Main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Circle {

public static void main (String[] args){
    double PI = 3.14159;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello, for this exercise we require that you input the Radius of the circle of your choosing: ");


}

}
```

I've really got two questions I suppose:
1) How to I take what I've got from my constructor class and bring it into my main method.
2) Where is the best place to define the "math" for the circle (IE 2πr etc).

Thanks!

Comment: I hate to sound flippant, however, if you've had three questions about Java in a single day...don't you think you should be reviewing your textbook a little bit more?

Comment: If you are allowed, you could use `Math.PI` instead of defining your own pi constant.

Comment: ...and remember, 22/7 was good enough for the Romans.  ;-)

Comment: On a side note, java has PI defined already, so you can reference `Math.PI` in your arithmetic, rather than defining it yourself.

Comment: Hey, at least Numpty wrote the code.  Let's cut him some slack.  His problem here is that he doesn't understand objects.  It takes time.

Comment: Thanks Guys - I'm aware of the built-in PI, we were just told to use that specific number. As for Max - I'm sure you had questions when you started out. If I wasn't reading my textbook, how would I know how to get this far? Thanks for the complete lack of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You would want to capture the input through the use of the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.  You would want to do sanity checks on whether or not they enter a word instead of an integer, but `Scanner` is a good place to start.
2. Any and all relevant operations to an object should belong inside of the object.  In your case, since a circumference relates to the circle, then you would be better served creating a method like `public double getCircumference()` inside of `Circle`.

Comment: Thank you Makoto - I definitely know I need to use a scanner for the input, but I'll try and move most of the methods to Circle so that it will be easier.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of having a class is to set those variables inside of your class.  In pseudocode what you want to do is:

```
  Main: Instantiate a new circle (which calls its constructor class)
        Circle: Set the internal (private and public) class variables of the circle
        Circle: Now has private variables set with the values you need to get into Main
  Main: Call a method on the Circle that does the Math you want
  (Alt. Use your getter classes you made like circle.getRadius in the main method to use these like 'variables')
```

For Math you can either put it inside the Circle, in your main class, or in a new class.  This takes a little figuring out and is up to your own specific object orientedey desires

Comment: Placing it in another class makes no sense.  Information about a class, including derived information (e.g. area, circumference, etc) would make more sense in the class than anywhere else.  It's a fundamental theory of OO design.

Comment: It depends, if Circle is a data object, he might want a specific 'Math' class to handle that.  Though you're right, he probably should have it inside of getCircle.  The naming convention is throwing me slightly here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-examine your Circle class.  A circle has one attribute.  This is commonly a radius or a diameter.

I prefer to have only empty constructors. YMMV.  I'd define the radius with a setter.

Then what can you do to a circle?  Add a method for each action:

```
getDiameter()
getArea()
getCircumference()
getRadius()
```

Comment: I've got to ask - if people like Max (and clearly others re: my lovely score) have issues with people trying to learn, can anyone suggest a site without an elitist/hostile mentality that I would be better served by? Thank you to all that are helping but...come on. The concept of this place is to in fact ask questions...

Comment: @numpty I intend no insult with this answer.  My approach would be to step back and re-examine more basic concepts about classes.  In this case, you see I named the class "Circle".  That's because nouns make great class names.  Your "GetCircle" is verbish.  Then once we have a Circle, _what_ can you do with a circle?  These imply the methods.

Comment: Hi Tony - You're probably right - I do need to investigate the underlying concepts a little further. I'm just a little taken aback by the general hostility here. Over in UL/SF we are significantly more noob friendly (not to say you specifically aren't, just the community in general)...

Comment: @numpty a question for you.  In the class I describe above, how would you implement getDiameter() ?